# Java regex get table alias from SQL query

Tags: java, regex

I am using the SQL Server 2017 database with a Spring boot project. I can not use JPA. Using spring JDBC. I have a requirement where I can add conditions to a query dynamically.

For example, there is a query already available in my properties file -

```
SELECT o.OrderID, c.CustomerName
FROM ECO.Orders o
INNER JOIN ECO.Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```

(ECO is my schema name and must include in the query)

Now, in java, I need to append conditions dynamically - eg. "`where CustomerID = 1`"

Problem with this is it will throw

> jdbc.SQLServerException: Ambiguous column name CustomerID

So I have to add an alias to this column.

"`where o.CustomerID = 1`" will work absolutely fine.

Now, I need to find a way to get an alias from the query.

I have tried following:

```
 String test = query.substring(query.indexOf("FROM ECO."));
 System.out.println(test);
```

Which gives following result :

```
FROM ECO.Orders o
```

I just need to get the Table alias from this. I guess this could be done with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the alias as shown in the following example using regex:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String queryString = "SELECT o.OrderID, c.CustomerName \n"
        + "FROM ECO.Orders o \n"
        + "INNER JOIN ECO.Customers c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID \n";
    deriveAlias(queryString);
    System.out.println("Alias: " + deriveAlias(queryString));
  }

  private static String deriveAlias(String queryString) {
    String query = queryString.replace('\n', ' ');
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*FROM ECO\\.[\\w]+ ([a-zA-Z]+).*");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(query);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
      return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
  }
```